# how to print a line resulting from a search keyword in a column using grep command,

Tags: linux, bash, unix, csv, grep

This is an example of a filename.csv file

```
"Sort Order","Common Name","Formal Name","Type","Sub Type"

"1","Afghanistan","Islamic State of Afghanistan","Independent State"    
"2","Albania","Republic of Albania","Independent State"    
"3","Algeria","People's Democratic Republic of Algeria","Independent State"    
"4","Andorra","Principality of Andorra","Independent State"    
"5","Angola","Republic of Angola","Independent State"
```

So what is the grep command to search for angola in common name and print it like this:

```
"5","Angola","Republic of Angola","Independent State"
```

I know that we can use:

```
grep '"Algeria"' filename.csv
```

However, what if I am being more specific. Let's say Algeria might exist in other column however, we only need to print the one in Common Name column.

I tried

```
grep '"Common Name | Algeria"' filename.csv
```

Seems not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `awk`

`awk -F"," '$2~/Algeria/' file`

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below grep command to print the lines which contains the string `Angola` in the second column.

```
grep -E '^"[^"]*","Angola"' file
```

This could be easily done through awk,

```
awk -F, '$2=="\"Angola\""' file
```

Comment: no, it must be `$2~/^"Angola"$/` . `==` will do an exact string match, then what's the need for regex.. We don't forget to include the anchors.

Comment: This is more correct command otherwise `$2~/Angola/` will also match `Angolans`

Answer (score 0):

Use `cut` command,

```
 grep Algeria filename.csv|cut -f2 -d','|awk -F '[""]' '{print $2}'
```

Output:

```
Algeria
```

Here is the explanation of all command I have added with your `grep` and discarded some unnecessary quotes you used in it.

`cut` command:

-f  It will extract 2nd column depending on delimiter

-d  It will choose delimiter i.e.: which is here `,`

`awk` command:

It will extract value between two `""` (block quotes) and print it.

Comment: `Algeria`, if present in a line, is always the second field, as per the data. So the entire pipeline would be effectively same as `echo Algeria` ;-) OP wants to print the entire line, which has `"Algeria"` as 2nd field...

Comment: @anishsane sorry I have misunderstand the question.